# change the name of the column of the dataset within the shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to have the ability to change the column name of the dataset within the shiny app through "colnames(data) <- c()". Is there any way to do that?
Here I have a reproducible shiny with a test dataset. could we use "textAreaInput()" to change the names of the column or there is a better way? Thanks for all your help.

ui.R

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

ui<-fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Basic DataTable"),
  
  # Create a new Row in the UI for selectInputs
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           selectInput("man",
                       "Manufacturer:",
                       c("All",
                         unique(as.character(mpg$manufacturer))))
    ),
    column(4,
           selectInput("trans",
                       "Transmission:",
                       c("All",
                         unique(as.character(mpg$trans))))
    ),
    column(4,
           selectInput("cyl",
                       "Cylinders:",
                       c("All",
                         unique(as.character(mpg$cyl))))
    ),
    column(4,
           textAreaInput("modify_code", "change the column names: ", 
                         "colnames(data) <- c()", width="600px")
           
           ),
  ),
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)
```

server.R

```
server<-function(input, output) {
  
  # Filter data based on selections
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
    data <- mpg
    if (input$man != "All") {
      data <- data[data$manufacturer == input$man,]
    }
    if (input$cyl != "All") {
      data <- data[data$cyl == input$cyl,]
    }
    if (input$trans != "All") {
      data <- data[data$trans == input$trans,]
    }
    data
  }))
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Do you want to change for the whole data or a set of columns?

Comment: @akrun I would like to be able to change the column's name of the whole dataset

Comment: You can pass it in `selectInput`, and then with in server code, `colnames(data) <- input$yourval` which should be a vector of values

Comment: @akrun could you perhaps show what you exactly mean? I tried the way you recommended, but nothing changed.

Comment: I posted a solution with what I thought you wanted.  Let me know if that is not your expected

Comment: @akrun thank you but it doesn't change the names of the column, only selects them and when deselected, changes them to NA. Lets's say we have a column, called "cyl_new", I want to change it to "cyl_old" perhaps or anything else. SelectInput wont do the job :/

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand what you really wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your heart is set on using textAreaInput, you could get your names from `input$modify_code`, split it into a vector, `new_col_names <- unlist(strsplit(input$modify_code," "))`, assuming each new column name is a single word (or use a separator). Then pass that to `datatable(data, colnames = new_col_names)` in the server side. The number of words you enter has to match the number of columns you're trying to rename. Is there a reason why you want the user to change the column names? You could rename at the server side when building your tables.

**EDITED**
sever side

```
server<-function(input, output) {
  
  # Filter data based on selections
  output$table <- DT::renderDT({
    data <- mpg
    if (input$man != "All") {
      data <- data[data$manufacturer == input$man,]
    }
    if (input$cyl != "All") {
      data <- data[data$cyl == input$cyl,]
    }
    if (input$trans != "All") {
      data <- data[data$trans == input$trans,]
    }
    
    ifelse(isolate(input$modify_code) == "",
           col_names <- names(data),
           col_names <- unlist(strsplit(isolate(input$modify_code),"|",fixed=T)))
    
    DT::datatable(data, colnames = col_names)
  })
  
}
```

No changes in the UI side. You need to enter exactly 11 names separated by | a bar. Like this `one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|eleven`.

What you enter in the textAreaInput is on hold until you change one of the dropdowns, otherwise it will try to change the column names as you type. You may want to put a submit button instead. This is just quick and dirty to get it working. It works, just tested it.

**EDITED:**
Forgot to put the second isolate...

Comment: Thank you for your response, This was merely a reproducible shiny app in order to give a better explanation. However, in the shiny app, I am working on, the user has to upload two different datasets where then, they go through a simulation loop, and changing the name of the column is crucial, in order to perform the simulation. The user wont have access to the server section of the app.

Comment: Also, "textArealnput" was merely a suggestion from my side, If you have any better idea, I would be happy to know

Comment: In that case, getting the user's input from the textAreaInput would work, but you have to clean it. If you have a small amount of columns, I would consider using textInput for each column name and reduce the amount of cleaning and possible problems with user input.

Comment: @ guasi, thanks, Could you perhaps make a reproducible shiny with the recommended changes, I implemented your recommendations, However, I only get errors.